# Facebook SDK not catching exceptions

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, api, sdk

I'm using the Facebook Graph API SDK in my Laravel 5.4 app ("facebook/graph-sdk": "~5.0" in composer)

I'm trying to fetch some fields from a page and when the page is invalid it throws an error, however it doesn't seem to catch the error properly:

Code below:

```
use Facebook\Facebook;

class FacebookUser extends Controller
 {
  try {
   echo 'Trying ' . $venue->id;
   $response = $fb->get('/'.$page.'/locations?fields=hours', $access_token);
  } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
   // When Graph returns an error
   echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   exit;
  }
```

This isn't ideal as it stops every time it hits a snag with the following error:

In FacebookResponseException.php line 106:

(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (hours) on node type (URL)

Comment: It outputs the error message and then stops, because _you told it to_ … If you don’t want that to happen, then don’t use echo and exit inside the catch block, duh.

Comment: is the exception you are trying to catch named `Facebook\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException` ?  as that is what you are trying to catch atm

Comment: @CBroe sure - if it was catching the exception then yeah that'd be a solution. But it's not catching the exception. I can remove that line and it still performs the same.

Comment: @lagbox I believe so - the error that's output to console is from FacebookResponseException.php ?

Comment: Well then it is probably an exception of a different type - you are only trying to catch those of a very specific type here. Either add catch blocks for other possible types as well, or one that catches _any_ kind of exception.

Comment: I have a feeling it is `Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException` not `Facebook\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException`

Comment: @lagbox tried changing it to include FacebookResponseException, FacebookOtherException, FacebookAuthenticationException, FacebookAuthorizationException,  FacebookClientException, FacebookServerException with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is most likely named `Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException`.

Because you have:

```
use Facebook\Facebook;
```

which is:

```
use Facebook\Facebook as Facebook;
```

you are ending up trying to catch this class:

```
Facebook\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException
```

You probably want to adjust your `catch` like so:

```
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
```